# Use a subclass with the Paper Trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

In my Rails app, I have a parent class `Assessment` with various subclasses `LanguageAssessment`, `MathsAssessment` etc. Every model in the application `has_papertrail` as this is on `ApplicationRecord`. When an item with a `LanguageAssessment` is deleted, Papertrail tries to access the `assessments` table and throws an exception, because it doesn't exist—it should be looking at the `language_assessments` table. Is there a way to tell it this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/362

> If you're using model inheritance for something other than STI you
> will need to override the base_class of the parent class like so:
>
> ```
> class LanguageAssessment < Assessment
>   has_paper_trail
>
>   def self.base_class
>     self
>   end
> end
> ```